# How to access json response data using Axios, node/express backend

Tags: node.js, json, express, axios

I have this project I’m working on and I am using node/express + Axios to retrieve data from a third-party API.

I am attaching an image of the response I am getting from my postman but,
I am having an issue figuring out a way to access and manipulate a specific set of data.
If there are any resources anyone could share that would help I would appreciate it.

as of now I just have:

```
    axios.get('apiUrl')
  .then((response) => {
    const cardData = response.data;
    res.send(cardData);   
  }
```

This is the response I get:
[image: postman response object]

for example, I’d like to access the “abilities” property.
Since that property is within the “0" object within the response object, I’m a bit confused as to how to navigate this in the code.

I’ve tried **response.data.0**  but that doesn’t seem to work.

Comment: `response[0].ability` (technically `response['0'].ability`, but the number is coerced to a string anyway)

Comment: Confusingly, your response has two members `request` and `response`, and you want to access `response.data.response[0].ability`.

Answer (score 1):

```
function retrieve(callback){
    //I don't get why you are using request.send here. Are you routing the response elsewhere?
    //If you are just consuming a service, use Axios with a callback instead.    
    //If you're not routing it you won't need Express.
    axios.get('apiUrl').then(response => callback(response));
}

function clbk(response){
    let obj = JSON.parse(response); //In case you are receiving a stringified JSON
    //Do whatever you want with the data
    //If you have a number as a key, access it by using []. So, considering your example:
    response.data[0]
}

//CALL:
retrieve(clbk);
```